# Setting fieldnames to a row other than the first for Dictreader in Python

Tags: python

I have a `csv` file where the table of data I am interested starts at say row 4.  When I try to skip over rows with something like yield, the `dictreader` still picks the first row for field names. I can get what I need by applying `islice` to the `dictreader`:

```
reader = islice(csv.DictReader(csv_file), 4, None)
```

But are there other ways that would also work?
I can’t seem to find any other way.

I am new and self learning, just trying to expand the way I approach things.

Comment: You are `islice()`ing the wrong thing... `reader = csv.DictReader(islice(csv_file, 4, None))`

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer